# Orders of elements a^{i}b in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G=\langle a,b : a^{12}=b^2=1,ba=a^7b\rangle$

I am trying to work out the number of elements of each order and am confused by the following:

Consider an element $a^ib ∈ G$. Now $(a^ib)^2=a^{8i}$

Here $a^{8i}$ has order $1$ iff $i ≡ 0$ (mod $3)$; and otherwise has order $3$. Therefore $b, a^3
b, a^6
b, a^9
b$ have order $2$, and the
remaining eight elements $a^i
b$ have order $6$.

I can't see why $b, a^3
b, a^6
b, a^9
b$ have order $2$?? I assume it's from the $a^{8i}$ fact but can't see how. Then I also can't see how the
remaining eight elements $a^i
b$ have order $6$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at $a^3b$. You have (from the "Consider" statement) that

$$
(a^3 b)^2 = a^{8 \cdot 3} = a ^ {24} = (a^{12})^2 = 1.
$$

with the last equality coming from the group presentation rule that $a^{12} = 1$.

As for the other elements...well, try raising one, say $g$, to the 6th power (using the "Consider" rule, and then cubing) to see that $g^6 = 1$. That means that the order *divides* 6. All you need to do is show that it's not 3 or 2 or 1, and you're done.